# netsh wlan show drivers (combine 2 commands in 1)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to add these two commands:

```
netsh wlan show drivers | find "administrator" && msg * "Please run as Administrator" && exit
netsh wlan show drivers | find "Hosted network supported  : Yes" || msg * "Your Wireless Network Adapter is not supported."
```

to make one single command with one `netsh wlan show drivers` but still functions like the two above, if the 1st command is processed, the 2nd will not be done.
Please help me.

Comment: The problem is the "&& exit" command in last part of the first command. Remove it and check your batch again.

Comment: no I mean I need "exit". I want the 2nd command to not be run if "Administrator" is detected

Answer (score 0):

```
netsh wlan show drivers && (netsh wlan show drivers | Findstr /i /c:"Hosted network supported" || Echo Not Supported) || Echo Please Run as admin
```

I don't have a WLan but I think this works. It's all about where the brackets go.

`&&` if previous command exit is 0. `||` if previous command exit is non zero.

Comment: not work, in addition I want just one "netsh wlan show drivers"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion 

    set "adminErrorText=administrator"
    set "hostedNetworkText=Hosted network supported  : Yes"

    (for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ('
        netsh wlan show drivers
        ^| findstr /l /c:"%hostedNetworkText%"  /c:"%adminErrorText%"
    ') do (
        if "%%b"=="" (
            msg console "Please run as Administrator." 
            exit /b 
        )
    )) || ( 
        msg console "Your Wireless Network Adapter is not supported." 
        exit /b 
    )

    echo OK
```

Answer (score 0):

for /f %%D in ('netsh wlan show drivers ^| findstr /i /c:"Hosted network supported  : No"  /c:"administrator"') do (
set x=%%D
if %%D==Hosted msg * /time:4 Your Wireless Network Adapter is not supported. && exit
)
set x | find "x=" && msg * /time:3 "Please right click the file -> Run as Administrator to start."